# Writing Color Calibration Data to a TIFF or PNG file

Tags: linux, image, graphics, image-processing, color-management

My custom homebrew  photography processing software, running on 64 bit Linux/GNU,  writes out PNG and TIFF files.   These are to be sent to a quality printing shop to be made into fine art.  Working with interior designers - it's important to get the colors just right!

The print shops usually have no trouble with TIFF and PNGs made from commercial software such as Photoshop.  Even though i have the TIFF 6.0 specs, PNG specs, and other info in hand, it is not clear how to include color calibration data or implement color management system on linux. My files are often rejected as faulty, without sufficient error reports to make fixes.

This has been a nasty problem for a while for many. Even my contacts at the Hollywood postproduction studios are struggling with this issue.  One studio even wanted to hire me to take care of their color calibration, thinking i was the expert - but no, i am just as blind and lost as everyone!

Does anyone know of good code examples, detailed technical information, or have any other enlightenment?  Or time to switch to pure Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at LittleCMS

http://www.littlecms.com/

This page has the code for applying it to TIFF

http://www.littlecms.com/newutils.htm

The basic thing you need to know is that Color profile data is something you need to store in the meta-data of the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a consultant called [Charles Poynton](http://www.poynton.com/) who specialises in this area.  I work for one of the post production studios you mention (albeit in london not hollywood), and have seen him speak on the subject a couple of times.  His website contains a lot of the material he presents and you might find something of use there.  He also has a book called [Digital Video and HDTV Algorithms and Interfaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607927) which is not as heavy as the title might suggest!  While these resources might not answer your question directly, it might provide a spring board to other solutions.

More specifically, which libraries are you using to write the png and tif files - you mention they are homebrew, but how custom are they exactly?  Postprocessing the images in an image manipulation program (such as [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) or [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/)) might allow you to inject this information into the header more successfully.

Sorry, I don't have any specific answers, but maybe something that will point you a bit further in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

As a GNU/Linux user, you’ll want to consider **DispcalGUI** – http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/ – a GNOME-based GUI that centralizes color management, ICC profile management, and (crucially for your case) device calibration. It can talk to well-known pro- and mid-level hardware, e.g, i1, X-Rite, Spyder, etc.

But before you get into that – you say you are generating your files to spec; are you validating your output using a test suite specific to the format in question? If not, here are three to get you started:

1. `imagetestsuite` supports the well-known formats: https://code.google.com/p/imagetestsuite/w/list?can=1&q=
2. The Luminous* test suite is a JIRA plugin, if that’s your thing: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.luminouslead.plugin.jira.testsuite.LuminousTestSuite
3. FLOSS Decoder implementations often have one you can use, i.e. OpenJPEG – https://code.google.com/p/openjpeg/wiki/TestSuiteDocumentation

But even barring all of those, it seems like your problem is with **embedded ICC data** – which is two specs in one. First, there’s the host image-file format, and they all handle embedding differently (meaning the ICC data will likely look totally different when embedded in a TIFF than, say, a JPEG or WebP file). Second, there is the ICC spec itself. It is documented here: http://color.org/v4spec.xalter – and you may also want to look at the source for the aforementioned dispcalGUI, which includes a very legible and hackable ICC profile class in Python: http://sourceforge.net/p/dispcalgui/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/dispcalGUI/ICCProfile.py

*Full disclosure: [I have contributed](https://github.com/fhoech/opi.py/commit/cbc1f1cdbbff4727ef0edbc8b2c1c7b8a5644f62) to that very ICC profile class, to which I just linked in that last ¶*

That’s the basics (many of which you have no doubt covered)... beyond that, if you post more information about what exactly is going wrong, I’d be interested to look it over. Good luck with it either way.

<sup>* NB. This project is unrelated to the long-standing photography website, “[the Luminous Landscape](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/)”</sup>